# Naming Convention for Custom Version of Builtin Function in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions

I've defined a custom version of Rails' `flash` function to add some functionality. Is there a naming convention in place for this?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you implementing this function? In the application_controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but make sure you give it a very descriptive name that describes why it is different to normal `flash`. Otherwise someone new coming along and seeing the code will probably be confused about what it is there for. I would consider putting an `_` at the start of it too.